# Dynamic web form, fields can be nested to arbitrary depth, also add/remove fields dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dynamic

I am trying to build a web form which will have its initial fields determined based on rows in a database.  For example, form 1 might have fields A, B, and C.  On the other hand, form 2 might have fields D, E, and F.  Additionally, there may be hundreds or even thousands of such forms, each with a unique ID.

Now, each one of these fields (A, B, C, etc) might in turn be made up of other fields, which in turn can be made up of yet even more fields.  In other words, some fields are actually collections of fields (to an arbitrary depth).

On top of that, the user of the form can choose to add more instances of some of these fields at runtime.  Sometimes the user will choose to add a whole new record (all fields) while at other times they may choose to only add another instance of one of the fields (which may itself contain more fields).  Also, I need the user to be able to remove any of these fields that they have added.

I've spent about 30 hours so far along with a colleague of mine coming up with a custom Javascript-based solution that involves building our own tree structure alongside the DOM tree, writing some recursive functions, etc but, as the complexity has mounted, it really seems like we were reinventing the wheel here.  This strikes me as a problem that must have already been solved at this point.

I'm not very familiar with jQuery but it sounds like it might potentially be a good solution based on what I've heard about it in the past.  In other words, I suspect that this might be a problem that jQuery more or less solves "out of the box."  But, my initial research into jQuery (on Stack Overflow and on Google in general) gives me the impression that this isn't the case and that a custom solution, using jQuery, needs to be put together.

My question is, what is the easiest way to achieve what I'm looking for?  The solution doesn't even have to use jQuery; I just thought that jQuery might be the best way to do it.  I'm not looking for someone to write the code for me, just to point me in the right direction since our solutions so far have looked pretty messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend checking [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html). With this Jquery plugin you can dynamically add or remove to you DOM using ko if: comments. Also, you can simply show or hide elements by using the visible data-bind. I would recommend checking out their tutorials the collections sections should give you a good start on how to implement what you are trying to.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're looking for, using jQuery combined with an easy to parse response framework like JSON would probably be what you're looking for. If you're using PHP you can pretty easily create a large nested array of form data and just print it out as JSON like this:

```
<?php
$form1Array = array(
    array('type'=>'text','name'=>'input_a','id'=>'input_a','value'=>'Example default value','label'=>'Input A'),
    array('type'=>'text','name'=>'input_b','id'=>'input_b','label'=>'Input B'),
    array('type'=>'password','name'=>'input_c','id'=>'input_c','label'=>'Input C'));

$form2Array = array(
    array('type'=>'text','name'=>'input_d','id'=>'input_d','label'=>'Input D'),
    array('type'=>'text','name'=>'input_e','id'=>'input_e', 'label'=>'Input E'),
    array('type'=>'password','name'=>'input_f','id'=>'input_f', 'label'=>'Input F','can_replicate'=>true));

$output = array('form_1'=>array('id'=>'form_1','label'=>'Form 1','elements'=>$form1Array,'can_replicate'=>true),'form_2'=>array('id'=>'form_2','label'=>'Second form','elements'=>$form1Array));

echo json_encode($output,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

That will obviously need to be modified to actually construct the structure from your database output, but that should be a fairly simple process. The output of that example will give you a nice JSON output that you can parse using jQuery:

```
{
    "form_1": {
        "id": "form_1",
        "label": "Form 1",
        "elements": [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "name": "input_a",
                "id": "input_a",
                "value": "Example default value",
                "label": "Input A"
            },
            {
                "type": "text",
                "name": "input_b",
                "id": "input_b",
                "label": "Input B"
            },
            {
                "type": "password",
                "name": "input_c",
                "id": "input_c",
                "label": "Input C"
            }
        ],
        "can_replicate": true
    }
}
```

After that, you'd just query your php page and assemble the output information into forms and elements:

```
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){ //wait for the whole document to load before modifying the DOM
                $.ajax({
                    url: "test.php",
                    success: function(data, status,  jqXHR) {
                        var formData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                        $.each(formData, function(id, formInfo){ // function(key, value);  In the PHP example, I used the key as the form ID, with the value containing the array of form data
                            var newForm = $('<form></form>'); //Create an empty form element
                            newForm.attr('id',formInfo.id); //Set the form ID
                            $.each(formInfo.elements,function(key, formInput){ //I didn't place a key on the inputs, so the key isn't used here
                                var newInput = $('<input></input>'); //Create a new empty input
                                newInput.attr({'id':formInput.id,'type':formInput.type,'name':formInput.name});
                                if(formInput.value != null){ //If a default value is given
                                    newInput.val(formInput.value); //Set that value
                                }

                                if(formInput.label != null){
                                    var newLabel = $('<label></label>');
                                    newLabel.attr('for',formInput.label); //Set the ID that this label is for
                                    newLabel.html(formInput.label); //Set the label text
                                    newForm.append(newLabel);
                                }

                                newForm.append(newInput);

                                if(formInput.can_replicate != null && formInput.can_replicate == true){
                                    //Place code here to insert a button that can replicate the form element
                                    //I'm just going to put a plus sign here
                                    newForm.append('<a href="#">+</a>');
                                }

                                newForm.append('<br />');
                            });
                            if(formInfo.can_replicate != null && formInfo.can_replicate == true){
                                //put code here to insert a button that replicates this form's structure
                            }

                            if(formInfo.label != null){
                                var newLabel = $('<label></label>');
                                newLabel.attr('for',formInfo.id);
                                newLabel.html(formInfo.label);
                                $('#form_container').append(newLabel);
                            }

                            $('#form_container').append(newForm);
                        });
                    }
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Testing</h1>
        <div id="form_container">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

After all of that, this is the output the example should produce:

[image: example output]